# Question about the lyrics of Sorry by Halsey

Tags: lyrics

I just listened to *Sorry*, a 2017 song by Halsey recently.

In the beginning, it says:

> I've missed your calls for months it seems
>
> Don't realize how mean I can be
>
> 'Cause I can sometimes treat the people
> that I love like jewelry

The character is saying that she is a mean person. Then why does she reason her meanness by saying the last sentence? The last sentence is showing kindness; not meanness.

In another part of the lyrics we have:

> Sorry to my unknown lover
>
> Sorry I could be so blind
>
> Didn't mean to leave you
>
> And all of the things that we had behind

If that's an **unknown** lover, then how did the character have a past with him?

Comment: Lyrics don't have to make sense.

Comment: Full explanation here: https://halsey.fandom.com/wiki/Sorry

Comment: @xhienne That doesn't explain the meaning of the lyrics.

Comment: Well to me treated a person like jewelry could mean valuing how much you like them, for purely selfish reasons.  You don't care how your jewelry feels, and don't even think about what makes it happy. :)  Jewelry only exists to make the person wearing it look better, so it's a tool for the owner, nothing more.

Comment: And from reading the linked page, which isn't a direct explanation but gives some hints...  I think "unknown lover" means a person who in hindsight was obviously interested but the singer was clueless and didn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd say that they didnt know that this person was in love with them. Maybe they were friends but that person never showed their feelings until it was too late or the singer didnt feel the same way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about the first question?